# Multiple Email Accounts on a Blackberry (with Exchange)

Tags: email, exchange, blackberry

I don't know where to begin to figure this out:

There is one administrative assistant that needs to retrieve e-mails on her blackberry for herself and two executives.  For one of the executives the e-mail also needs to go to another admin assistant's blackberry.  Their IT department says "This can't happen."  They've asked me to quietly look for a solution.

So, where should I begin my search?

Answer (score 2):

You can forward to the email address of the blackberry, or connect it to the exchange server via OWA. See this thread about BBs and Exchange.

Is the assistant concerned about all the mail in the same location on the BB? It could easily be done by forwarding the exec's mail to the BB mail account, but things would be jumbled up.

[Can Blackberry devices sync directly to Exchange?](https://serverfault.com/questions/41673/can-blackberry-devices-sync-directly-to-exchange/41694#41694)

Answer (score 1):

The feature your admin assistants are using is [delegate access](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook/HP052421361033.aspx). Bob the Boss can delegate access to his entire inbox, just the calendar, or selected subfolders. The BlackBerry doesn't support delegate access to mailboxes as far as I can tell. There's at least one [third-party product](http://www.wicksoft.com/) that claims to provide support for delegated calendars but I haven't tested it. I don't know of any solutions for delegating access to the inbox itself, which is what it sounds like you're asking for.

Answer (score 1):

You can have multiple POP/IMAP email accounts but not multiple exchange accounts.  You can set up exchange to forward emails to the assistant but not full access to the executive's emails on the blackberry.

Answer (score 0):

Without forwarding the email to the other users account, the wizard of oz is right.  blackberry's are designed to be 1 user 1 email account devices

Comment: You can have multiple email accounts on a Blackberry.  I've read you can also connect to multiple BES servers if you rename your service book, but I haven't tried it myself.

Comment: You can have multiple email accounts not multiple exchange accounts- you would have to forward the mail, although as I think about it I suppose another option would be to write a hub transport rule to duplicate all the mail.

Answer (score 0):

I had to do something like this before.  What we ended up doing is creating an Exchange account for the Blackberry itself.  We would create a group with all the users that need to have their email go to the Blackberry and added the group to the "Forward to:" in Active Directory/Exchange.  This allowed for the email to go to the Blackberry without having to go to the individual's Exchange mailbox as well.